# Crashed Google Chrome display under Windows 8.1, how do I revert a faulty flag?

Tags: google-chrome

Trying to fix the Google Chrome display under Windows 8.1, I changed a the flag  `HiDPI` in `chrome://flags` from `Default` to `Enabled`, and as a result, things are worse, and now the Google Chrome display is completely garbled to the point that I cannot even revert back from the UI the flag. Does anyone know how to revert the flag from the config files?

Answer (score 0):

Run Chrome with command line argument --no-experiments. It will ignore any changes made. Then change the value of flag from settings.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-experiments
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not works. The faulty flag is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can start Chrome with the command-line switch `--no-experiments`.  That doesn't revert the changes made to the chrome://flags, but instead causes them to be ignored for that run of Chrome.  You should then be able to go to `chrome://flags` and reset the HiDPI flag.